# execute multiple CMD line commands and display output in one text box for Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm looking to capture the output of multiple command line commands, and display the output in one text box, one after the other. Using Visual Basic.

I'm currently using this example in a button which works great for one command:

```
    Dim oProcess As New Process()
    Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo ("ipconfig", "/all")
    oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    oProcess.StartInfo = oStartInfo
    oProcess.Start()

    Dim sOutput As String
    Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = oProcess.StandardOutput
        sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
    TextBox1.Text = sOutput
```

So for example if I had several commands like:

hostname

whoami

systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"Host Name" /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Model" /C:"System Type" /C:"OS Configuration" /C:"Domain"

ipconfig /all

How would I stack the output in the text box one after the other?

[VB pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwjVw.png)

Comment: Firstly, don't use fake tags. If this is a VB.NET question then it clearly has nothing to do with VBA, so don't use the VBA tag.

Comment: As for your question, you should specify "cmd.exe" as the file to execute, so that will open a command prompt and leave it open until you close it.  You can then redirect standard input as well as standard output and pass your multiple command in one by one.

Comment: Regarding the tags, my mistake. I’m looking to automate the commands and output rather than leave the window open.

Comment: But if the window doesn't stay open after executing the first command, how can you execute the second? Open the window by running "cmd.exe", redirect the input and output streams and then you can execute as many commands and get their output as you like, because you have an open command window to execute them in. Once you've executed them all, THEN you close the window.

Comment: As for displaying the outputs in your `TextBox`, call its `AppendText` method.

Comment: Thanks for your help @jmclihinney, the AppendText works great. I'm still looking to automate the process some how with one click rather than type all the commands in at the cmd.exe window one after the other.

Comment: I've already told you how to do that... twice!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the output of a single command in an array or in variables (sOutput1, sOutput2, sOutput3, etc) and concatenate all the results in a text box:

```
TextBox1.Text = sOutput1 & Environment.NewLine & sOutput2 & Environment.NewLine & sOutput2
```